# GitHub wikis and Markdown

Tags: github, wiki, markdown

Reading about the GitHub wikis, I saw that they support several lightweight markup languages including MarkDown, but I am still a bit confused about the status and features of Markdown and the version GitHub uses.

**Q1.** In this link:  [Introduction to the GitHub flavored Markdown (GFM)](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/), GitHub says they use `GFM`, a special type of Markdown (`MD`) for messages, issues and comments. Do they also use `GFM` or regular `MD` on their Wikis?

**Q2** Is the original Markdown still under development?

**Q3** Does the **original** Markdown support programming-language specific syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do they also use GFM or regular MD on their Wikis?

Not the whole **[GitHub Flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/)** can be used in the wiki pages.

For instance, in the wiki, something like `#123` won't autolink to issue 123 from the current repository. However, in a Pull request or a inline comment, this works.

> Is the original Markdown still under development?

Not that I know of. Lastest official release is dated December, 17 2004.

In order to fix some security issues, the code has been forked by the StackOverflow team and hosted at **[derobins/wmd](https://github.com/derobins/wmd)**. It's now deprecated in favor of **[PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/)**.
GitHub relies on **[Sundown](https://github.com/vmg/sundown)**, a native reimplementation of MarkDown based on the UpSkirt library by Natacha Porte.

> Does the original Markdown support programming-language specific syntax highlighting?

No. This might even be considered as borderline against the philosophy of MarkDown.

The site indeed states *"Markdown is intended to be as easy-to-read and easy-to-write as is feasible. Readability, however, is emphasized above all else. A Markdown-formatted document should be publishable as-is, as plain text, without looking like it’s been marked up with tags or formatting instructions."*

GitHub handles the syntax hightlighting through the use of **[Pygments](http://pygments.org/)**.

Comment: Thanks! But I am confused with your answers to Q1 and Q3. GitHub wikis support programming-language specific syntax highlighting (I can use the syntax ``````ruby\n code\n code\n````). Also, as far as I understand the `````code```` syntax was not supported by the original MD. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right! I've updated the answer. Code blocks were also part of the original MarkDown specs. However, this was relying on indentation instead of backticks.

Comment: Thank the lord they don't use GFM in the wiki and other `.md` files. Although most of GFM is nice, the whole "all line breaks are hard line breaks" is a terrible design for anything except little web comments.