# How does Github render the .wiki extension?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I've just added a .wiki file (`foo.wiki`) to a Github repository. To my surprise, it is rendered as HTML by Github.

Which wiki syntax does Github use? What is their rendering engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [GFM](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown), GitHub supports [a number of other markup formats](https://github.com/github/markup#markups), including Textile, Perl Plain Old Documentation, Emacs Org-mode, and ReStructured Text.

Though no support is explicitly listed for `.wiki` files, there *is* support for Mediawiki syntax in `.mediawiki` files. If I had to guess, I'd guess that `.wiki` files also use [Mediawiki syntax](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aFormatting).

**Edit:**

The OP has confirmed that `.wiki` files use Mediawiki syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Up until yesterday (May 1st, 2014), the wiki editor was more a plain text editor, with a subset of GFM ([GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/30713/2853372/9806a9ea-d143-11e3-9840-c480e22e38aa.png)) supported (as described in "[GitHub wikis and Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12500857/6309)", and detailed in "[Editing Markdown for GitHub](https://moduscreate.com/editing-markdown-for-github/)".

This is now changing, and the editor should be more consistent with the regular Ace editor used for GitHub repo data.

See "[Wikis: now with more love](https://github.com/blog/1828-wikis-now-with-more-love)"

> more consistent rendering of wiki content alongside other markup in a repository

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/30713/2853372/9806a9ea-d143-11e3-9840-c480e22e38aa.png]

Answer (score 0):

GitHub uses "GitHub Flavored Markdown," or GFM, across the site--in issues, comments, and pull requests. It differs from standard Markdown (SM) in a few significant ways, and adds some additional functionality.

If you're not already familiar with Markdown, take a look at [Markdown Basics](https://help.github.com/articles/markdown-basics). If you'd like to know more about features that are available in issues, comments, and pull request descriptions, such as task lists, read [Writing on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/writing-on-github).

[On GitHub,](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) you can see the differences between Markdown and GFM: plenty information are available there to master GFM and Markdown.

Markdown was developed by John Gruber: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

In wiki pages you can use **MediaWiki** syntax, but you have no facilities nor you'll be able to preview the result.

Comment: Actually, GitHub supports [a number of other markup formats as well](https://github.com/github/markup#markups). I think the OP was asking what it uses for files called `.wiki`, but unfortunately that is not included in the list I linked. The closest is likely `.mediawiki`, and if I had to guess I'd guess that.

Comment: Chris, seems that you're right. The syntax is that of Mediawiki.

Comment: @MartinMonperrus, I have added a separate answer containing this information.